# MongoDB replica set on windows facing some basic issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am on Windows 10 Environment. I would like to Implement Replica Set on MongoDB. I am facing some issues..

For that, I cover almost many tutorials to implement the things on Windows Machine.

I want to create a replica set consisting of a primary node and another node, which will be replicating the data.

My structure is like this:

- Install folder: C:/Programs Files\MongoDb\Server\3.4\bin\
- Database folder: C:/data/db
- Log file folder: C:/data/log
- Config: C:/data/mongod.cfg

I have defined the service with this command:

> sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\data\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"

I have started the service with this command:

> net start mongodb

It runs successfully.

However, now I am getting problems with replication. What I did to set up the replica set is:

1. create three subfolders under the data folder named *rs1, rs2, rs3*, using the command `mkdir \data\rs1 \data\rs1 \data\rs2`
2. Implement the Replset for replication of three servers.

My three startup commands are:
1. start mongod --replSet udd --logpath \data\rs1\1.log --dbpath \data\rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
2. start mongod --replSet udd --logpath \data\rs1\2.log --dbpath \data\rs2 --port 27018 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
3. start mongod --replSet udd --logpath \data\rs1\3.log --dbpath \data\rs3 --port 27019 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64

With those running, I can type `mongo --port 27017`; this connects properly to 127.0.0.1:27017/

Now my problem is that earlier the mongo shell prompt said *udd:PRIMARY>*; but now it has changed to say: *udd:OTHER>*

Please guide me how I can move forward with replication; any help is really appreciated.

My rs.reconfig(config,{"force":true}) will be

```
    udd:OTHER> config =  {_id: "udd", members: [
... {_id: 0, host: "127.0.0.1:27017"},
... {_id: 1, host: "127.0.0.1:27018"},
... {_id: 2, host: "127.0.0.1:27019"}
... ]}
{
        "_id" : "udd",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:27018"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:27019"
                }
        ]
}
udd:OTHER> rs.reconfig(config,{"force":true})
{ "ok" : 1 }
udd:OTHER> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "udd",
        "date" : ISODate("2018-01-31T11:58:15.717Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "term" : NumberLong(1),
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
        "optimes" : {
                "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                        "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                },
                "appliedOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1517381781, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "durableOpTime" : {
                        "ts" : Timestamp(1517381781, 1),
                        "t" : NumberLong(1)
                }
        },
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 1506,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(1517381781, 1),
                                "t" : NumberLong(1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2018-01-31T06:56:21Z"),
                        "configVersion" : 37530,
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27018",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-01-31T11:58:15.677Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.",
                        "configVersion" : -1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "127.0.0.1:27019",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDurable" : {
                                "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                        },
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2018-01-31T11:58:15.670Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                        "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                        "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.",
                        "configVersion" : -1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
udd:SECONDARY>
```

Now rs.conf() will be

```
udd:SECONDARY> rs.conf()
{
        "_id" : "udd",
        "version" : 37530,
        "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1),
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:27018",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "host" : "127.0.0.1:27019",
                        "arbiterOnly" : false,
                        "buildIndexes" : true,
                        "hidden" : false,
                        "priority" : 1,
                        "tags" : {

                        },
                        "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),
                        "votes" : 1
                }
        ],
        "settings" : {
                "chainingAllowed" : true,
                "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000,
                "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
                "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000,
                "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : 60000,
                "getLastErrorModes" : {

                },
                "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
                        "w" : 1,
                        "wtimeout" : 0
                },
                "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("5a715e56bff9fd66ea55b862")
        }
}
udd:SECONDARY>
```

Comment: Weird formatting makes the question unreadable. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and fix the typos. The mess with rs0, rs1, rs2, rs3 is really confusing.

Comment: How are you initiating your replica set? Please show your replica set config. Aslo your output shows a RepSet name of `udd` but starting `mongod` your repSet name is `sfr`. What are you using your `mongo.cfg`? If you're starting `mongod` with command line options??

Comment: @N3i1 Actually I am following the tutuorial steps. I need Only 1 replica set. And yes udd is sfr. for hiding some info i will edit sfr to udd

Comment: @AlexBlex really sorry for that. I edited the question. Please go through it if you can.

Comment: @N3i1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okrZdlO9_3Q

Comment: I already did. error msg is: Already initialized . And It is not on PRIMARY. currently state is OTHER not PRIMARY

Comment: You've no mention of running any `rs.` commands in your question

Answer (score 0):

Clear error message: InvalidReplicaSetConfig

All 3 rep mongod are started, then try:

```
rs.reconfig({force:true})

db.isMaster()
```

Comment: when I will do rs.initiate() it returns error msg: already Initialized. and Pointed to OTHER not on PRIMARY

Comment: Question is updated with rs.conf() and rs.status() result

Comment: why it will be on secondary not on primary?

Comment: The `reconfig force` option will force a reconfiguration even on a secondary. So now you just need to find which one is your primary, problem solved

Comment: I solved it. First I will create the service for both the server and then start primary server. Its automatically converted into primary

Comment: And Thanks a ton @N3i1. You Supported me from last Hour. Really appreciate for your effort and help